# Positioning children widgets at the center and at the end of a Column parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to position 2 children widgets inside a Column parent widget. I want one of them to be positioned in the center and the other at the end of the column. What is the best way to do that?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // this is wrong, it positions both the widgets in the center
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('This text should be at the center of the column'),
          Text('This text should be at the end of the column'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [Spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) widget like this:

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(),
          Text('This text should be at the center of the column'),
          Spacer(),
          Text('This text should be at the end of the column'),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the top Text will always be offset up by the height of the bottom text because it's actually centered between the Spacers, and then the bottom text will shift everything up by its height.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean, i added more widget and it still looked fine!

Comment: Increase the font size and it becomes more visible. Your way causes the top text to be off-center by half the height of the bottom text. I edited the code in my answer because the character limit in a comment won't let me do it here.

Comment: well yeah you are right, but the guy just wanted to show Texts one at center and one at bottom and i gave him just that, i actually think more than that in not necessary.

Comment: I really do think they specifically asked it the way that he did because  they were trying to center the middle one in the center of the column regardless of what was below it. If they were just trying to center it in the remaining space above the bottom text, I think the question would have been phrased differently.

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT: I changed the code and added grey to mine in order to show a comparison, so you can see what I mean when I say it will be offset by half. You have to increase the font size to see the difference.)

It's not quite as easy as the other answers because the first text has to be centered and if you only use two elements in your Column then no matter what you do it's either going to make the top item be off-center by half the height of the bottom text (as in using only two Expandeds) or the design will be rigid and therefore may not display correctly on different sized devices.

So, the trick is to use three Flexibles (2 Expandeds and a Spacer). Put the Spacer on top. It and the bottom Expanded must have the same flex value in order to center the middle Expanded.

Only then will using "alignment: Alignment.center" give the needed result for the top text.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CenteringOneItemWithAnotherItemInTheColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  const CenteringOneItemWithAnotherItemInTheColumn({
    Key key,
  }) : super(
    key: key,
  );

  /// Adjust these values as needed
  final int sameFlexValueTopAndBottom = 40; // 40%
  final int middleFlexValue = 20; // 20%

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Column Alignment Question'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Spacer(),
              const Text(
                'Cent',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 64,
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              const Text(
                'Bot',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 64,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              /// The key is to have the Spacer and the bottom Expanded
              /// use the same value for flex. That will cause the middle
              /// child of the Column to be centered vertically.
              Expanded(
                flex: sameFlexValueTopAndBottom,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: middleFlexValue,
                child: const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'Cent',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 64,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: sameFlexValueTopAndBottom,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                  child: const Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Text(
                      'Bot',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 64,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This will look like it's lower than center to the eye because it's not centered in the available space, it's centered in the column.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use an empty `SizedBox` at the start and the `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,`

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 0.0,
            width: 0.0,
          ),
          Text('This text should be at the center of the column'),
          Text('This text should be at the end of the column'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [Spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) will be a much better choice than an empty `SizedBox`

Comment: I see where you're going and that's great outside-the-box thinking, but I worry that the problem with this would be that the SizedBox and Text being different heights would cause the middle text to be offset upward by (half?) the difference in height.

Answer (score 0):

**One of the way could be using Expanded widget along with alignment as for the need**

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // this is wrong, it positions both the widgets in the center
        children: <Widget>[

          Expanded(child: Container(alignment:Alignment.bottomLeft,child: Text('This text should be at the center of the column'))),
          Expanded(child: Container(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft, child: Text('This text should be at the end of the column'))),
        ],
      ),
    );


  }
```

[image]

Comment: The top Expanded is going to be the height of the available space minus the other Expanded. So, if you center text inside the top Expanded, it will be offset upward by (half?) the height of the bottom Expanded. So, it won't quite be centered.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But I dont think @Marco Gelli  is asking that precise.

Comment: Actually, I think they were. I think they already knew how to center the item in the middle of the space above the bottom text. I'm pretty sure that's why they were specifically asking how to center it in the column as a whole even when there is something else below it.